# Relative path for web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a VB.NET web application for which I am using an Excel file as my DB. In my local system I can access that file by giving the full path. In the server I can't give the full path because it will vary, so I need to give the relative path.

How can I access an Excel file by giving its relative path in my VB.NET application?

Comment: Any feedback about my suggestion? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the path where your application is running:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

combine:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myExcel.xls")
```

or (for console and windows forms)

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

combine:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "myExcel.xls")
```

If you're talking about asp.net application then you can do:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "myExcel.xls")
```

or, again:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myExcel.xls")
```

Comment: i tried SorceFile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("DashboardDB.xlsx") already in locel itself it is failing it is giving the path like C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\MYExcel.xlsx in this path the file was not present. when i try above thing am getting error like "application is not a member of my"

Comment: First of all we have to agree where your file is. Is it going to be where the executable (`.exe`) is?

Comment: file is there in the same path where my aspx page is there

Comment: Then you'd better use: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.